# bash for loop performance

Tags: bash, performance, for-loop

i have started diving a bit deeper into bash lately and noticed that running the following for loop is taking a significant amount of time.

I'm curious to know what i am doing wrong ?

```bash
time bash -c '
x=0
for ((i = 0; i < 5000000; i++)); do
   if [[ $i -gt 500 ]]; then
       x=$i
   fi
done
echo $x
'
```

Output :

```bash
4999999

real    0m15.522s
user    0m15.519s
sys     0m0.000s
```

```bash
time bash -c '
x=0
for i in {1..5000000}
do
   if [[ $i -gt 500 ]]; then
       x=$i
   fi
done
echo $x
'
```

Output :

```bash
5000000

real    0m12.952s
user    0m12.549s
sys     0m0.400s
```

I have tried something similar using node and python

```bash
time node -c '
let x = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < 5000000; i++) {
  if (i > 500) x = i;
}
console.log(x);
'
```

Output :

```bash
4999999

real    0m0.098s
user    0m0.083s
sys     0m0.010s
```

```bash
time python3 -c '
x=0
for i in range(5000000):
    if i > 500:
        x=i
print(x)
'
```

Output :

```bash
4999999

real    0m0.369s
user    0m0.369s
sys     0m0.000s
```

---

EDIT: to really write a loop to do the above in "`bash`" would be:

```
time bash -c '
x=$(
    awk "
        BEGIN {
            x = 0
            for (i = 0; i < 5000000; i++) {
               if ( i > 500 ) {
                   x = i
               }
            }
            print x
        }
    "
)
echo "$x"
'
4999999

real    0m0.324s
user    0m0.265s
sys     0m0.000s
```

`awk` is the mandatory POSIX general purpose text processing tool and so it will be present on all POSIX-conformant Unix boxes for `bash` or any other shell to call to manipulate text without needing to install any other tools such as `node`, `python`, `perl`, `ruby`, etc.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303157/is-there-something-wrong-with-my-script-or-is-bash-much-slower-than-python

Comment: Note that the "faster" 12-second version takes a lot more memory than the 15-second version, because it generates the list of integers and then loops through that list -- whereas the "slower" one only stores one integer, the current counter, at a time; thus making it vastly more memory-efficient. Using microbenchmarks to decide what constitutes good code in bash (when the changes aren't orders-of-magnitude scale) is not generally a great idea.

Comment: To directly answer your question, though: You're doing nothing wrong. For a shell interpreter, 3,000,000 loop iterations per second is not slow at all. There's no _good reason_ to optimize it further, because shell interpreters are largely used to start other processes and plumb them together, and the overhead of starting other processes is so large as to make the execution time you're seeing disappear into the noise floor.

Comment: (One part of that: To the extent that bash _has_ an integer type, you're not using it! So every time you increment the number, it's being converted from a string to an integer, incremented as an integer, and then being converted back to a string. That's normal and expected: the integer type bash _does_ have is a nonstandardized extension, and while it would make your code a bit faster, I don't recommend using it; there's more value to being a bit slower but substantially more portable).

Comment: General comment: Don't use `bash` when performance is important. It's not what it's intended for.

Comment: Anyhow -- I'm voting to close this question as opinion-based, insofar as there's no practical problem here. You have _a personal expectation_ about what performance should be relative to other language runtimes, but an expectation does not a practical problem make. There _are_ common mistakes people make that result in performance problems substantial enough to make bash a poorly-chosen language for use cases that it's otherwise suited to, but none of those mistakes are present in the code at hand; there's nothing to fix.

Comment: comparing bash and python, you're seeing the difference between just interpreting strings and compiling into bytecode.  Each iteration of the loop in bash will re-parse the string that is the body of the loop to figure out what to do, while python will parse the whole loop once and convert that to bytecode.  Interpreting the bytecode is much faster than reparsing the loop body every time.

Comment: It's easy to accidentally create shell loops that are slower than necessary through excessive forking, but this loop doesn't do that and instead just reflects the speed of the interpreter.